# Create anchor text inside .innerhtml javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a subscription form where user selects service and number of hours. Onsubmit I call a function which displays the result/total price. The function looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calc()
{
var total = 0;
var course = 0;
var nrOfLessons = 0;
var vat = 0;


course = Number(document.getElementById("course").value)
nrOfLessons = Number(document.getElementById("nrOfLessons").value)
total =(course * nrOfLessons)
vat = total * 0.15
total = total+ vat;
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "The total is "+total+" Click here to Pay

}
</script>
```

Now my question is this. How can I change the text from above "click here to pay" into a link. I tried everything that I can think off but I am stumped.

Thanxs in advance for all the help. Please try to keep answers newbie friendly :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can turn that into a *link* by using:

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 
    "The total is "+total+" <a href='[url-here]'>Click here to Pay</a>";
```

Replace `[url-here]` with the URL of your payment page.

Comment: Why italics the word link?

Comment: Thanx tech. The problem was with my quotation marks i was using double not single

Comment: One more question if you dont mind... how can I get a small pop up window to open when user clicks the link?

Comment: You can use window.open - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open